# Is there a compiler memory barrier for a single variable?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction

Compiler memory barriers has the effect among other things to force the compiler to make sure **all** stack variables that are cached in registers are written to memory before the barrier.

For example, GCC has the following statement:

```
asm inline ("" : : : "memory");
```

Is there any way to tell a compiler (specifically GCC, but I'm interested in others as well) to do the same effect for only a **specific** variable? something like the following imagined construct:

```
int x;
...
asm inline ("" : : : "memory(x)");
```

With the expected behavior that the value of x and x only will be written to the corresponding memory location, if it happens to be cached in a register.

The reason for this is that I have a specific variable which I need to make sure is not cached in a register so that a hardware engine can read its value. However, a full compiler memory barrier will force the compiler to write to memory the value of **all** other variables that might be cached in register at that point in time as well which can amount to much more data then I need to write. I wondered if there something more specific.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with `{ int y = x; *(volatile int*)&x = y; }` and inspect the resulting assembly.

Comment: Right! and it seems that for my need even `*(volatile int*)&x = x;` works just as well. Thanks a bunch! :-)

Comment: just liked simple sollution +1

Comment: If `x` was in a register, it act as required. However, if `x` was already committed in memory, it will load/store it again.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are willing to work with gcc extensions you could use the extensions for atomic instructions for that feature:

```
__sync_bool_compare_and_swap(&myvar, 0, 0)
```

would set the value of the variable to `0` if it is already `0` :) and in addition imply a full sequential consistency on that memory location.

Answer (score 3):

Recollecting one of the threads on lkml, one of the methods for single variable compiler-only barrier is:

```
#define forget(x) __asm__ __volatile__("":"=m"(x):"m"(x))
```

Comment: A side note: this is a full barrier (that force store to memory and force reload from memory). You can obtain a write barrier with `__asm__ __volatile__(""::"m"(x))` and a read barrier with `__asm__ __volatile__("":"=m"(x))`

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can achieve it by specifying your variable in the list of output values of `asm`:

```
__asm__ __volatile__ ("" : "=r" (x) : : )
```

See [Extended Asm](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) for some information.

### UPD.

It may be better to use `"g"` constraint instead of `"r"` as more permissive.

```
__asm__ __volatile__ ("" : "=g" (x) : : )
```

Also, I've found another [great howto](http://ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html) for inline assembly.

Comment: Nope, first of all neither g or r constraint will work because they allow to put the value in a register. I thought an "m" constraint on the address of x might work but gcc emits an error about memory input 0 not being directly addressable. Thanks for trying though :-)