# What is the light(est) weight GCC memory barrier in such case?

Tags: c, gcc, concurrent-programming, memory-barriers

I have the following C code:

```
...
data[index] = something;
a_write_memory_barrier();
index = new_index;
...
```

The code is not protected by a lock(others just read `data` and `index`), I want to make sure `data[index]` is stored before the updating of `index`.  There are memory writes and reads of other variables around this code, but they do not matter, so GCC can freely reorder them(and I hope it does so for optimization). Just guarantee the order of `data[index]` and `index` is enough. How should `a_write_memory_barrier()` be implemented to achieve this goal?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896092/is-there-a-compiler-memory-barrier-for-a-single-variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to care about out of order execution (you probably work in a distributed framework), that you need to think of load load , store store and full barriers , of course if your architecture supports TSO (total store ordering) than you don't care about store barriers, your write operation will be sequential as written in the code.

If you from the other hand worry about compiler reordering , think of using Volatile (google it)

In your example store barrier will solve your problem , the implementation of such a barrier is dependent on the architecture and a compiler that you use:

e.g.

for sparc and gcc compiler :

```
   #define MEMBAR_STORESTORE()  asm volatile ("membar #StoreStore":::"memory")
```

Comment: The code you provided is a memory barrier that prevents reordering of any stores and loads around it. I just want to prevent reordering of `index` and `data[index]`, not others.

Comment: hmm... thanks, but, if there are, say `a=1; ... (code block in the question) ... b=2;`, won't the `MEMBAR_STORESTORE()` also prevent reordering of `a=1` and `b=2`? Is there something that just prevents specified reordering? In the question, just keep the order of writing `data[index]` and writing `index`, other writes around them are OK to reorder.

Comment: @W.Sun: read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896092/is-there-a-compiler-memory-barrier-for-a-single-variable, it actually discusses mostly compiler re ordering , there are some workaround for a memory address barrier , i am not sure that this will work in a distributed framework , the best way is to put a store store barrier for all store commands. all the CAS solution enable an atomic update but not garentie order